# How are satellite resx files used, depending on the language and/or country culture?

Tags: .net, localization

Our WPF solution consists of a number of projects, each containing a resource file called "Strings.resx" containing UK English strings.

If I was to add a satellite resource file called "Strings.*fr*.resx", am I right in saying that this would be used regardless of whether the app's UI culture is "fr" or a more specific culture like "fr-CA" or "fr-BE"?

If I wanted to go a step further and localise the app for a specific country (e.g. Belgium), and added a resx file called "Strings.*fr-BE*.resx", I'm assuming this would only be used if the UI culture was "fr-BE", while all other French cultures (e.g. "fr" or "fr-CA") would continue to use "Strings.*fr*.resx"?

Lastly, if a string key is missing from "Strings.fr-BE.resx", will the app look in the "parent" language file instead ("Strings.fr.resx")? And if the key is missing from this then I assume it would look in "Strings.resx"?